# I am creating highchart with wicket. I am getting issue in multiple x-axis

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng, dotnethighcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am creating highchart with wicket. I am getting issue in multiple x-axis. 
So my requirement is

I've one Y-axis which will show the values.
I have two x-axis.
so let's assume the data is in format

| Period     |    Name     |     Data     |

|:-----------|------------:|:------------

| 08/2015    |        A    |     10
| 08/2015    |        B    |     15
| 08/2015    |        A    |     17
| 09/2015    |        B    |     19
| 09/2015    |        C    |     20
| 10/2015    |        B    |     21
| 10/2015    |        C    |     23

I am able to create simple Name-Data bar chart having name as X-axis and passing all the values of name as categories and data in Y-axis. 
But now I have to create a bar chart with 2 X-axis. other X axis will just mark the start and end of period in first X-axis. So my bar chart will have another axis marking the period the x-axis data belongs to.

Comment: So with which part do you have a problem? Create another series which belongs to the second xAxis - it should have two values - the start of the first series data (10) and the end (23).

Comment: 10-23 is the data corresponding to Name(X-axis)..  My X axis has Name as values. Sub(second) x axis should be period and it should be used for grouping name (x-axis)

Comment: Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and create a live example, e.g. on jsfiddle. Without the example I can only repeat myself. You might want to look at the grouped categories plugin https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories